# Method with JsonObjectRequest Failing without any Errors

Tags: java, android, json, https, jsonobjectrequest

**FIXED: ** Android Studio does not seem to sync new permissions from AndroidManifest when app is recompiled and run. I updated the manifest with:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Then uninstalled my app from the emulator. This fixed the error. Cheers to those who replied!

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here. This is my first attempt at using JsonObjectRequest for a Uni project and am having some trouble. I am trying to use the OpenSea API to get a list of the 20 most recently minted NFTs (this is just practice with calling an API for an Android app), and I cannot figure out why the request is not completing.

See code:

```
private void getFirstNFTList()
    {
        Log.d("Personal", "Reached get method");
        String url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?format=json&limit=20&offset=0&order_direction=desc";

        final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                Log.d("Personal", "Reached onResponse");
                try
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("assets");
                    int length = limit;

                    Log.d("Personal", "Reached try");

                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    {
                        Log.d("Personal", "Reached For");
                        JSONObject a = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String test = a.getString("image_url");
                        Log.d("Personal", test);
                    }
                    Log.e("Personal", String.valueOf(response));

                } catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    Log.d("Personal", "Reached Had JSON Error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO: Handle error
                Log.d("Personal", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        });
        Log.d("Personal", "Reached mQueue");
        mQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Here's where my problem is. In Logcat, the only "Personal" logs made are "You got here", "Reached get method", and "Reached mQueue". There are no other lines between these three (in Logcat) in Android Studio either. It seems that my JsonObjectRequest is failing but my try/catch isn't producing any errors. For reference, I'm expecting a log-word-vomit of image urls from the first 20 NFT assets provided.

I don't think this is where my problems are coming from, but here's a quick link to OpenSea's API reference anyways for your convenience: https://docs.opensea.io/reference/getting-assets

Any idea where I'm making my mistake? I can provide more of my code/logs if needed.

Comment: There is something missing in the code, like, from where are you getting the value of `limit`? As `limit` decides your `length` , if `length` is 0, the for loop will be skipped. try printing the values of `limit` and `length`

Comment: To me it looks like the request is not executed because no listener fires. How do you initialize the mQueue?

Comment: Limit is set in another method but is instantiated at 20. My code isn't even reaching the try/catch to get to the loop. As for mQueue, it is instantiated in my onCreate() method, here is the line:

`mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);`
@DrHopfen